# UIPageViewController between two UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I've just started programming in Swift, what I'm trying to accomplish is a very simple app with an initial `UIViewController`, a `UIPageViewController` that shows some book pages and a destination `UIViewController`.

My approach so far is this:

1. The `UIViewController1` is loaded and has a showPage button that simply shows `UIPageViewController`

`present(walkthroughViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

2. When the user reaches the last page of the `UIPageViewController`, I show the destination `UIViewController2`, addressing the segue from the start `UIViewController`

   ```
   override func onUIPageViewControllerRigthClosing(){
       let pvc = self.presentingViewController as! StartPageController
       dismiss(animated: true){
           pvc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "startTest", sender: nil)
       }
   }
   ```

Everything works correctly, but the problem is that when `UIPageViewController` is dismissed, the Starting `UIViewController` is showed and then is showed the second with the animated segue. 
What I am trying to achieve is to directly display the target `UiViewController` to the user on the dismiss of the `UIPageViewController`, without showing the transition with animation from start View to the destination View.

I'm completely wrong approaching or there is a way to do the segue before dismissing the `UIPageViewController`?

Here I created a gif that shows the problem, when I close the `UIPageViewController` I see the previous view in transition: [GIF demo](https://i.imgur.com/JFWoutq.gif)

Comment: could you share sample code?

Comment: Do you mean the complete project? because the code is already in the application, practically the first step is on the click of a button, the second method is called when the pages of the UiPageViewController are finished

Comment: @AntonBelousov I modified the question by adding a Gif, I hope now the problem is clearer than before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you using this approach: for these screens transitions use childViewControllers instead of presenting them modally and dismissing with default UIKit functions.

You have problems with naming, so let me rename view controllers.
Say, you have:

- `RootViewController` (the first screen, user see after
  app launch).
- `OnboardingViewController` (your pageViewController or other container)
- `AppContentViewController` (actually app main screen)

I suggest you using this approach: for screens transitions on `RootViewController` use childViewControllers instead of presenting them modally and dismissing with default UIKit functions.

Here is sample code that works with childViewControllers

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayChildController(_ content: UIViewController, duration: TimeInterval = 0.4, animation: (() -> ())? = nil, completion: @escaping () -> () = {}) {
        content.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        view.addSubview(content.view)
        addChildViewController(content)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animation != nil ? duration : 0, animations: {() -> Void in
            animation?()
        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
            content.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            completion()
        })
    }

    func hideChildController(_ content: UIViewController, duration: TimeInterval = 0.4, animation: (() -> ())? = nil, completion: @escaping () -> () = {}) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animation != nil ? duration : 0, animations: {() -> Void in
            animation?()
        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
            content.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            content.view.removeFromSuperview()
            content.removeFromParentViewController()
            completion()
        })
    }
}
```

Here is "algorithm":

I assuming that you are using single storyboard with all these view controllers.

1. On `OnBoardingViewController` declare `onDoneCallback`:

   ```
   class OnBoardingViewController: ... {
       var onDoneCallback = {}
       ...
   }
   ```
2. On `RootViewController` when you need present `OnboardingViewController`:

   ```
   func presentOnboardingScreen() {
       let onboardingVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnboardingViewController") as! OnboardingViewController
       onboardingVC.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height)

       onboardingVC.onDoneCallback = {
           self.presentAppContentAfterOnboarding() // see below
       }

       displayChildController(onboardingVC, duration: 0.3, animation: {
           vc.view.transform = .identity
       })
   }
   ```
3. When you need call `onDoneCallback` closure on `OnboardingViewController`
4. `presentAppContentAfterOnboarding` method on `RootViewController` could look like:

   ```
   func presentAppContentAfterOnboarding() {
       let onboardingVC = self.childViewControllers.last as! OnboardingViewController
       let appContentVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AppContentViewController") as! AppContentViewController
       displayChildController(appContentVC)
       view.insertSubview(appContentVC.view, belowSubview: onboardingVC.view)
       hideChildController(childVC, duration: duration, animation: {
           onboardingVC.view.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height)
       })
   }
   ```

Note. Don't forget to set **Storyboard ID** of `OnboardingViewController` and `AppContentViewController` in your storyboard.

Here is the [sample project](https://github.com/AntonBelousov/SimpleVCTransitions)

Comment: Thank you very useful! I was hoping for a method that would allow me to use the segue, but I think it's impossible

Comment: Well, it look's like there is not convenient way to do this using only segues